# Sublime Text 4 pressing Esc doesn't close the autocomplete box

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext4

I'm on a mac, with a new installation of Sublime Text 4, no settings tampered with and pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key isn't closing the autocomplete box as it used to in sublime text 3. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you remapped `Esc` in the macOS settings?

Comment: @MattDMo nah, never

Comment: Have you restarted your computer and Sublime? If that didn't work, open the console with `Ctrl+\`` and enter the command `sublime.log_input(True)`. Keep the console pane open while you type something into a source file to trigger autocomplete, then hit `Esc`. Do you see `key evt: escape` in the console?

Comment: You should also `sublime.log_commands(True)` as well; it should log either `hide_auto_complete` or nothing at all; if you see it logging the key but running a different command, you have a key binding blocking it

Comment: @MattDMo I haven't restarted my computer and its funny, as soon as I opened my console, the esc key to exit autocomplete started working!!!